# Sending .pdf file to server using Qt-creator

Tags: tcp, qt-creator, tcpclient

I'm working with Qt-creator on Ubuntu. I have to send a pdf file to my server on my network using TCP Connection. I'm making the client side application.

I have googled a lot but couldn't find any pointer to the solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: QtCreator is just an IDE, and you want to write application (in c++). You have to open pdf as a file and send it bit by bit through QTcpSocket.

Comment: I mentioned Qt because it may have custom library to easily deal with my issue. Anyhow, how to do that in C++? Any link ?